# Generating a List of random Integers with condition in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here I am trying to generate a list of Integers where I want to add random numbers to the list while the condition where `md<=1` is not satisfied.
I tried several times but with no luck.

```
fx :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
fx md s = do
  x <- randomRIO (1,min md s)
  if md<=1
     then return [md]
     else return md:(fx (md-x) s)
```

Comment: What _exactly_ doesn't work here?

Comment: You might find it simpler to return `IO [Int]` and separate out the filtering function to a separate pure function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is at the last line:

```
else return md:(fx (md-x) s)
```

The result of `fx` is in the `IO` monad, and with that result you want to perform a pure operation of prepending `md` to it. This is exactly what [`liftM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) does, your last line should be

```
else liftM (md :) (fx (md-x) s)
```

---

Other small improvements:

- You don't really need `IO`, you only need to generate random numbers within the function. For this you could use the [`MonadRandom`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.3.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom) type class (residing in the package with the same name). This will make the function more specific, type-safe and flexible.
- It's redundant to generate a random number and only after then check if you need it - the comparison `md <= 1` doesn't need `x` at all.

So an improved version might look like:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Random

fx :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> Int -> m [Int]
fx md s | md <= 1   = return [md]
        | otherwise = do
              x <- getRandomR (1, min md s)
              liftM (md :) (fx (md-x) s)
```

---

#### alternative without `liftM`

maybe this is easier to understand:

```
fx :: (MonadRandom m) => Int -> Int -> m [Int]
fx md s | md <= 1   = return [md]
        | otherwise = do
              x  <- getRandomR (1, min md s)
              xs <- fx (md-x) s
              return (md : xs)
```

Comment: maybe it's easier to see if you just fetch the recursive results inside the do block - I allow myself to add this to your answer - feel free to delete it again if you don't like it

Comment: Thats great . `liftM :: Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r` . `fx :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
fx md s = do
  x <- randomRIO (1,min md s)
  if md==1
     then return [md]
     else liftM (md:) (fx (md-x) s)

`

Comment: more options: `fmap` = `<$>`